# summernote note-popover appearing in top left on clicking button to add editor

Tags: javascript, html, popup, editor, summernote

I have a problem with summernote.

I've got adding note-popover appearing in top left on clicking button to add editor.
[here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NIkb.png)

Anyone else have that problem?

[here is a screenshot of the DOM tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxSWF.png)

I have last version of the summernote from their website [0.8.9]

```
 $(discription_list).summernote({
        // width: editorWidth,
        toolbar: [
          ['font-style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'clear']],
          ['para', ['ul', 'ol']],
          ['misc', ['undo', 'redo']],
          ['savebutton', ['save']],
          ['cancelbutton', ['cancel']],
        ],
        buttons: {
          save: SaveButton,
          cancel: CancelButton
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution, if this helps someone.

```
     $(discription_list).summernote({
        // width: editorWidth,
        popover: {
          image: [],
          link: [],
          air: []
        },
        toolbar: [
          ['font-style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'clear']],
          ['para', ['ul', 'ol']],
          ['misc', ['undo', 'redo']],
          ['savebutton', ['save']],
          ['cancelbutton', ['cancel']],
        ],
        buttons: {
          save: SaveButton,
          cancel: CancelButton
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a conflict between summernote and bootstrap 4 that causes that error to display, after unzipping summernote file use summernote-bs4.css and summernote-bs4.js to display. This will show no popover on the top left

```
    <link href="summernote/summernote-bs4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <script src="summernote/summernote-bs4.js"></script>
```

[View Issue on Gitlab](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/2275)